# Springboot Spring Security Ldap Login page not showing up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I created a springboot application with spring security dependencies.
I following some tutorials and most of the say the same. I add the dependencies needed and then create a websecurityconfig file. I created these and when I run the project on my local host it works fine. I pushed my application to a remote server and I am not seeing the login page.
Here are my list of dependencies

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

And here is my websecurity config

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

         @Autowired
         LdapConfig ldapConfig;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(); 

        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
            return new CustomUserDetailsContextMapper();
        }   

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder>.ContextSourceBuilder contextSourceBuilder = auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchBase(ldapConfig.getUserSearchBase())
                    .userSearchFilter(ldapConfig.getUserSearchFilter())
                    .groupSearchBase(ldapConfig.getGroupSearchBase())
                    .groupSearchFilter(ldapConfig.getGroupSearchFilter())
                    .groupRoleAttribute(ldapConfig.getGroupRoleAttribute())
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                    .contextSource();

            if (ldapConfig.getPort() != null) {
                contextSourceBuilder.port(ldapConfig.getPort());
            }

            contextSourceBuilder 
                    .root(ldapConfig.getRoot())
                    .url(ldapConfig.getUrl())
                    .managerDn(ldapConfig.getManagerDn())
                    .managerPassword(ldapConfig.getManagerPassword());
        }

    }
```

This has eaten up a lot of my time, any one Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a Not Authorized when trying to get to the login page ?

Because it looks like you are requiring someone to already be authenticated to access it.

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin(); 

    }
```

You'll need something similar to

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin(); 

    }
```

to allow the login page to be reached.

Comment: The same code is working on my local host, i do not think it is the issue with antMatcher missing. Anyways, I gave it a try and it did not work. My application works fine on localhost, it is presenting me the login page and after login I can go to my home page. On remote server I am not being presented with login page and when I try to call it directly I am getting 500 error.

Comment: hmm I see ...  Are there possible firewall/networking/proxy issues with the remote server ?

Comment: I am not sure James, Is there a way to identity? I enabled debug logs and found that the following lines are missing in the remote server.

Comment: I enabled debug logs and found that these lines are missing in the remote server.
.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/XXXX/]
.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.

Comment: Assuming that XXXX is the removal of private info ... and not the actual URL? lol

Comment: XXXX is my application name and is part of the actual URL.

Comment: Seems like some issue with my remote server, I pushed to another server and it is working as expected. Thankyou to all who looked into this issue.